# How to get surrounding method in Java source file for a given line number

Tags: java, parsing, line-numbers

I have a line number of a Java source file and want to get the sourounding method for that line number programatically.

I looked into [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) which didn't help me much.

Janino (http://www.janino.net) seems promising, I would scan and parse (and if necessary compile) the code. Then I could use [JDI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/index.html) and

```
ReferenceType.locationsOfLine(int lineNumber)
```

Still I don't know how to use JDI for doing this and didn't find a tutorial that goes anywhere in this direction.

Maybe there is some other way that I am completely missing.

Comment: Are you talking about the same way diff -U will? e.g. @@ -3452,6 +3452,59 @@ void MyMethod(int a, int b)

Comment: You want the method name, or the text of the method?

Comment: Method name would suffice, but problem is long solved. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using Java 6, and if you don't mind using Sun's APIs, then you can use [the javac API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html). You'll need to add `tools.jar` to your classpath.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import com.sun.source.tree.CompilationUnitTree;
import com.sun.source.tree.LineMap;
import com.sun.source.tree.MethodTree;
import com.sun.source.util.JavacTask;
import com.sun.source.util.SourcePositions;
import com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner;
import com.sun.source.util.Trees;

public class MethodFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnosticsCollector = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnosticsCollector, null, null);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects = fileManager.getJavaFileObjects("path/to/Source.java");
        CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnosticsCollector, null, null, fileObjects);

        // Here we switch to Sun-specific APIs
        JavacTask javacTask = (JavacTask) task;
        SourcePositions sourcePositions = Trees.instance(javacTask).getSourcePositions();
        Iterable<? extends CompilationUnitTree> parseResult = null;
        try {
            parseResult = javacTask.parse();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // Parsing failed
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (CompilationUnitTree compilationUnitTree : parseResult) {
            compilationUnitTree.accept(new MethodLineLogger(compilationUnitTree, sourcePositions), null);
        }
    }

    private static class MethodLineLogger extends TreeScanner<Void, Void> {
        private final CompilationUnitTree compilationUnitTree;
        private final SourcePositions sourcePositions;
        private final LineMap lineMap;

        private MethodLineLogger(CompilationUnitTree compilationUnitTree, SourcePositions sourcePositions) {
            this.compilationUnitTree = compilationUnitTree;
            this.sourcePositions = sourcePositions;
            this.lineMap = compilationUnitTree.getLineMap();
        }

        @Override
        public Void visitMethod(MethodTree arg0, Void arg1) {
            long startPosition = sourcePositions.getStartPosition(compilationUnitTree, arg0);
            long startLine = lineMap.getLineNumber(startPosition);
            long endPosition = sourcePositions.getEndPosition(compilationUnitTree, arg0);
            long endLine = lineMap.getLineNumber(endPosition);

            // Voila!
            System.out.println("Found method " + arg0.getName() + " from line " + startLine + " to line "  + endLine + ".");

            return super.visitMethod(arg0, arg1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)'s CodeVisitor to [retrieve the debugging line information](http://asm.ow2.org/asm153/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/CodeVisitor.html#visitLineNumber%28int,%20org.objectweb.asm.Label%29) from a compiled class. This saves you the parsing of Java source files.

```
ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(A.class.getName());
reader.accept(new ClassVisitor() {
    public CodeVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
            String[] exceptions, Attribute attrs) {
        System.out.println(name);
        return new CodeVisitor() {
            public void visitLineNumber(int line, Label start) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}, false);
```

For class A:

```
11  class A {
12  
13    public void x() {
14        int x = 1;
15        System.out.println("Hello");
16    }
17
18    public void y() {
19        System.out.println("World!");
20    }
21 }
```

This produces:

```
<init>
11
x
14
15
16
y
19
20
```

If you need this information at runtime. You can create an exception and have a look at the [stack trace elements](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29).

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this good answer. This is almost what I was looking for. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can throw an Exception, catch it, extract the corresponding stacktrace element to get the method name.

Comment: There's not need to parse the stack trace. The stack trace element (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) contains the information.

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. I have to get the method of a class that I am not using.